# How to convert sql query to linq entities?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

```
INSERT INTO StudentInformation3.NewSameStudents (StudentID, Image)
SELECT s1.StudentID, s1.Image
FROM StudentInformation.student s1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM StudentInformation2.NewStudent s2 
              WHERE s1.StudentID = s2.StudentID
             );
```

My goal was to add 2 tables to the other table by comparing the fields.And I do this with sql.But I have a student model and I want to do this with entities.

How do I do with Entities insert?

Comment: The short answer is `context.Students.Add(myStudent)`. The long answer is you may need to do an entity framework tutorial :) Entity Framework hides the details of SQL and focuses on objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same SQL. Both Linq To SQL and Linq To EF support executing direct SQL commands. This type of commands are better suited to do with SQL thus you could do that with a direct SQL. ie:

```
context.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO StudentInformation3.NewSameStudents (StudentID, Image)
SELECT s1.StudentID, s1.Image
FROM StudentInformation.student s1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM StudentInformation2.NewStudent s2 
              WHERE s1.StudentID = s2.StudentID
             );");
```